# Sitegenesis for SFRA

Tags: community, commerce-cloud

I am beginner in SFRA so I want to start with exploring Sitegenesis and Sitegenesis Global. Where can I get the Code and How can I set it up on my sandbox.

Comment: Is this a commerce cloud question? If so please add the appropriate tag

Answer (score 1):

you can learn more about how to get started with SFRA by reading the instructions here: https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/SFRA/GettingStartedwithSFRA.html

There's also documentation about the older SiteGenesis architecture available here:
https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/GettingStarted/Sitegenesis.html